# How to customize SKIN in Richfaces?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, customization, skin

I want to customize whole look and feel of my web application.
Currently I am using Richfaces 4.1.0.

## 1st Trial:

To customize the SKIN I tried to follow http://www.packtpub.com/article/skin-customization-in-jboss-richfaces-3.3

1. Added mySkin properties file.
2. Updated build.xml
3. Updated web.xml.

But All this is not fruitful. I am not able to customize the SKIN.

## 2nd Trial:

Ref Link:- http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_1_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming.html

```
<context-param> <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name> 
<param-value>emeraldTown</param-value> </context-param>
```

But this is also not working. To get it working am I required to add any additional **RESOURCE**?

## 3rd Trial:

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="client" style="width: 70%;margin: auto;background-color:red;">
            
                <rich:tab header="Overview">
                    Tab 1 Content
                </rich:tab>
                <rich:tab header="JSF 2 and RichFaces 4">
                    Tab 2 Content
                </rich:tab>
            
        </rich:tabPanel>
```

I tried to put background color **Explicitly**, but even this is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried few Different things, but for

## 1st Trial &

## 2nd Trial

I found the solution.

```
 <mime-mapping>
            <extension>ecss</extension>
            <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
        </mime-mapping>
```

was missing in `web.xml`, on adding the above line, I started to get expected results.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize skin in Richfaces at three level.

**Using property files of skin**

you can modify the Application interfaces by changing the values of skin parameters in the skin. for that you need to Edit the constant values defined in the skin.properties file to change the style of every component mapped to that skin property.

**Using Component stylesheets**

Mappings and other style attributes listed in a component's ECSS file can be modified. Edit the content of ECSS file to change the styles of all components of that type.

**Using Custom components style classes**

you can also specify styleClass attribute to Individual components. For that add the new style class to the application CSS and reference it from an individual component with the styleClass attribute.

**By Overwriting stylesheets in application**

You can also load custom stylesheets using  which rewrites of extends styles defined for style classes of components.

for detailed information refer http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_1_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming.html

Comment: I went through the shared link. I tried <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>emeraldTown</param-value>
</context-param> ..But this is not working, am I required to add any new file?

Comment: does it able to find the skin file on specified path (classpath) path?

Comment: For Trial 1) how to check if its able to find the skin file on the specified path?

Comment: make sure that your mySkin.skin.properties file lies in the src folder of your code so that when the code is compiled, it is also put along with the binaries.